# How does "It's totally fucked" translate to Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

The closest I can manage (uneducated) is "Prorsus Futui Est," but I suspect that's somewhat (if not completely) wrong.

Comment: Are you asking for a translation of the literal or the figurative?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Latin verb *futuere* is a good translation for the English verb "fuck" in the sense of sexual intercourse.
The past participle *fututus* means "fucked" in this sense.
As often in Latin, this can be intensified with a prefix.
The adjective *defututus* can well be translated as "totally fucked", although many dictionaries give much softer translations like "exhausted by sensuality" in Lewis and Short.

If you do not want to specify what "it" is and you want to refer to sexual intercourse, then *defututum est* is a good translation for "it's [been] totally fucked".
The English verb can be used in a number of different meanings, but I assumed the literal one.
If you meant something else, please edit your question to clarify what the message you want to convey is.

The translation you suggested (which sounds like what Google Translate might give) is not grammatical.
It does find a good verb, but the whole doesn't quite work.

Comment: I would think it is short for "It's totally fucked up.", which roughly means "It is in a exceedingly broken state". But I'm not very confident, because it is the most versatile verb of the English language, as far as I know. (I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel you are correct, another more gentle way of saying it would be 'this is totally messed up' or 'it's a complete/total disaster' . the word fuck in this case doesn't refer to sex at all, which is why I don't think this answer is accurate but to be fair I doubt there actually exists a latin translation that is 1:1 with the english.

Comment: I think if you're going to translate *fucked* in a literal sense, then you're better off using either masculine or feminine gender.

Answer (score 14):

As Joonas said, I would use a form of the participle *fututus*, literally "fucked". Here's one example, from Catullus VI:

> *Cur? Nōn tam later' **ecfutūta** pandās,*
> *nī tu quid faciās ineptiārum*
>
> Why? Because you wouldn't display your **fucked-out** body like this unless you were doing something obscene.

(In this poem, Catullus is saying it's obvious that Flavius has a mistress because of the way he looks when he goes out in public.)

Or, from Catullus XLI:

> *Āmeāna, puella **dēfutūta**,*
> *tōta mīlia mē decem poposcit!*
>
> Ameana, that **thoroughly-fucked** girl, asked for a full ten thousand!

(In this one, he's complaining about Ameana's prices being too high.)

In both of these, notably, the adjective refers to the literal act of sex—I don't know of any case where it's used metaphorically, like in English "fucked up". But I'd have no qualms using it that way, since the metaphor and the obscenity are clear enough.

Comment: I remember your quest for an expletive intensifier. Yourself suggests, I think, that the phraseology in your answer would not qualify as perjorative; expletive-type bad language. If Roman soldiers were addressing each other, good-naturedly, or otherwise how would they say: "Fuck you!"; "I'm fucked-off with this!"; "Fucking hell, not again"? Is it so that "futuere", in Latin, is about as offensive as "to make love", in English?

Comment: @tony "Futuere" is certainly more vulgar and offensive than "to make love".

Answer (score 6):

Since all current answers address the sexual meaning of "fucked", I will provide alternatives for the case of "fucked" => "broken".

> #### Fractus
>
> Broken, shattered

or its related

> #### Confractus
>
> Destroyed

Both of these can of course be used with an optional intensifying prefix to provide the "totally" ingredient.

The full phrase could be translated as:

> Perfract(-us/-a/-um) est

Comment: Can you specify which prefix you think works on *fractus*?

Comment: @Wilson _per_ seems reasonable, and is at least used by John Paul II in _Reconciliatio et Paenitentia_.