# Could one consider using Latin as a daily casual language these days?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, contemporary-latin, modern-life

I just saw a video asking like how would one say **I just had an avocado toast** and thought about some of the new stuff that didn't exist back then. How would we integrate new words into the Latin language.

For example, *computer* or *a car* or *television* or *I have an Xbox One*

From the last 2 weeks that I have spent learning Latin I have fallen in love with it and really wanted to be able to fluently speak it and write it but these type of questions make me doubt sometimes that the Latin language could be used like English or Spanish for example.

Are we limited to what was known or spoke in the Roman times? I asked as well how would one say good morning in Latin but the answers I got were that they didn't really had any time greetings, just *salve* but couldn't we maybe be able to come up with a *good morning* sentence in Latin since the modern days that's how we usually greet in the morning?

Comment: Nobody's going to stop you, but if you're willing to make up whole new ahistoric idioms, not just out of necessity coin a few words for things that didn't exist in Antiquity, I'm not sure what the point of the exercise is.

Comment: What do you mean by *the point of the exercise*?

Comment: Paulum dē hāc rē [hīc](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latinitas_viva) lege, plus Anglicē [hīc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_Latin#Living_Latin).

Comment: You also might want to see [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13248/is-a-translation-from-modern-english-to-latin-meaningful/13285#13285) from [Sebastian Koppehel](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/6567/sebastian-koppehel). I would say this in Latin but I'm still learning like you. ;)

Comment: @BenKovitz Maxime miserandum est plerasque paginas Vicipediae Latinae tam brevis esse.

Comment: Unfortunately the Finns ended their Latin radio service. That would have been interesting for you.

Comment: wait i thought the point that latin is a dead language means that the answer is negative?

Comment: Don't blindly translate Good morning to Latin. That's like our Duolingo users complaining that the translation of Dobrý den must be Good Day and cannot be Hello. Different languages have different greetings.

Comment: @BCLC People who claim Latin is a dead language usually do not know what they are talking about, and are actually intending to say that there are no (known) native speakers of Latin as a first language. There’s a very big difference between that and a language being dead (Esperanto and Interlingua, as well most other conlangs, and an increasing number of minority cultural languages, are largely in a similar situation, though many of the minority cultural languages are dead or dying as well as they are not actively evolving).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn i thought latin [really is dead and just not extinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinct_language)? if not, then ok not dead and not extinct but then what? Edit: wait the wiki article actually says 'In contrast, a dead language is "one that is no longer the native language of any community", even if it is still in use, like Latin' --> so either it's wrong or it has a different definition from you?

Comment: @BCLC I’ve always been told that ‘dead’ in terms of linguistics means the language is no longer evolving (no new words, no loan words, etc). Usually this translates to a complete lack of vernacular usage, and typically also very limited formal usage as well. If the definition given by Wikipedia is the standard one among linguists though, then even though Latin is dead, that does not preclude it from being actively used, because there’s a big difference between no native speakers and the language not being in any active usage.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn is latin dead according to wiki definition? is lating dead according to your definition?

Comment: Consider that vulgar/vernacular Latin diverged from classical Latin pretty much immediately, and that vulgar Latin + 2000 years of evolution = Spanish (and also Italian, French, etc.).

Comment: Yet how, for example, did computer or car or television or Xbox come into english or any other language? Duh!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You seem to be addressing several issues in this question.

To start from the bottom line: **Latin is already being used right now as a daily casual language.** Not even a small reserve about this statement.

The external world changes, and new words are born. It happens in every language and Latin is no exception to that. New words are finally integrated into the community - the question of *how* this process happens is different question. Thus "the community" (As far as I can speak of a "community") has *pipiatorium* for Twitter (from the verb *pipio*) and *Tutubum* for YouTube.

I personally wouldn't be compelled at all to have *good morning* that is not *salve*. Morning, it seems, did exist in antiquity already, but no "good morning" different from "good evening" was used. Actually, I would actually oppose any attempt to incorporate the innovation into the language (but as a living language, at the end something is settled), simply because, for me at least, those differences are part of the beauty in languages. In short I wouldn't like to speak English in Latin, but to speak Latin.

Comment: The process of adding new words is what I would like to know. Do you know any article for this?

Comment: @JohhanSantana Alter fōns est [_Lexicon Recentis Latīnitātis_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicon_Recentis_Latinitatis), nexūs ad alterōs [hīc](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicipaedia:Noli_fingere) incipiunt.

Comment: *Tutubum* is even better than the original name!

Comment: Why are company/website names translated? You can't go to pipiatorium.com or tutubum.com.

Comment: @Barmar, That's a good question. But as a matter of fact they got translated. Latin has declination system for nouns, so that might be a good reason to have a Latin name so the words will fall about a declination category.

Answer (score 14):

Latin is used regularly within the Vatican and Catholic Church, so depending on what you mean by daily usage I think that fulfills that requirement. There are also a lot of loan words that make their way into modern Latin, both historically and currently. For example, [Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicipaedia:Pagina_prima), the Latin version of Wikipedia.

Latin is also used regularly on this site for casual conversation within chat, not to mention some questions are also written and answered entirely with Latin.

While I don't see myself ordering groceries in Latin, I do see myself using Latin on a daily basis for the rest of forever (or as close to it as I can get).

Regarding what you are limited to, it really depends on what your goal is. Are you looking to only use Latin as it was known within a specific time frame like the first century common era, or are you open to adding in loan words or novel constructions? There's really no right answer with this as long as it's grammatically correct. It's just personal preference, really.

Comment: Loaning of words? How would that work? And from which language could we loan words from?

Comment: Loan words can come from any language. The Romans themselves incorporated words from across the whole empire and beyond, not unlike almost any modern language. _How_ this is done varies of course, and I can think of a number of different ways a word can make its way into another language, by design or by chance. You could post another question specifically about methods of transition words from another language into Latin, if you wanted.

Comment: An awful lot of Latin words were lifted from Greek; historia etc. Anything with th or ph.

Answer (score 2):

There's Dr Ammondt singing Elvis songs in Latin, for some idea of how picking up modern terms and usage might work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=II5Zvt6xJ-g